# Using IOS and facebook APIS

Tags: ios

Hi Does any one know how to use facebook chat apis with ios, I have use git command from the steps followed here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ios/ after that i dont have any idea how to create a sample app and what syntax to follow. Thanks a lot

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't yet worked with the FB SDK, but their [guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ios/) says

> The Github repository contains a sample application that showcases the iOS SDK features.

And indeed here's the sample: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/DemoApp
You should check this sample app first. You can just open the *DemoApp.xcodeproj* file from your local git clone folder.